# iOS: Call method in tabs viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar, viewcontroller

I'm trying to come up with something simple, but i can't figure it out.

I have a UITabBarController and at one point I have to display another tab's UIViewController, and call a method in that new UIViewController, using data from the original UIViewController.

So basically I want to pass data to another UIViewController (that may not be initialized yet), and show the right tab.

If I use `NSNotificationCenter`, I'm not sure if the tab's UIViewController is initialized yet, and also it's a bit ugly to use delegation here.

What is a clean way to send and show data in the new tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better idea would be to have a protocol implemented in the tab view controller the view controller can call to send data and set up any other view controller

Comment: Don't know why you got down voted, your logic is sound and it would seem to me that if the original poster has to create a singleton just for passing this particular piece of data around then this would be a better solution.

Comment: Yes, Thank you! It should be noted that by using a protocol the view controller is logically decoupled. If possible the view controller shouldn't have any knowledge of what needs to happen anywhere in the system except in its own little world; it just informs its delegate (if one is assigned) that something has happened and lets the delegate decide what to do with that information. There is absolutely no need to couple things with a global singleton as was suggested in other solutions. Staying decoupled makes life easier for testing, readability, and makes the code less "fragile" to change.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 1; //this is the view controller you want to go to.
MySecondViewController *secondViewController = (MySecondViewController *)self.tabBarController.viewControllers[x];
[secondViewController setDataObject:dataObject];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:x];
```

So what's happening is you're calling the controller from the tabBarController, it will initiate there if its not. Then you can set whatever you want on the controller, then you just switch to the selected tab.

Comment: Better, but now your view controller is coupled to a tab bar controller. A protocol is cleaner.

Comment: I was only providing the solution to the questioner's immediate question. I'm a strong believer that the model and its business logic be separate from the controller stack.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a data model of some sort (singleton?) that is accessible by both view controllers. When the second view controller is about to display its view, it should reference the data model to determine the data it should display.

Comment: Even though my solution works, this is the proper way to handle data in an app. iOS uses the MVC paradigm and a singleton/coreData/etc. model separates your data logic from your controller logic. Its almost always better to have a heavier model and a lighter controller.